# Excel 2013 error when launching Excel files

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a user with a strange issue I have never seen before.

When double clicking an Excel 2013 file on the Windows 7 Desktop, he gets this error:

`There was a problem sending the command to the program`

The first thing I did was run an Office repair, no luck.

After doing some research, I found:

- Double-clicking the file on the Desktop causes the error
- Launching Excel then opening the file works fine
- Dragging the file to the Excel.exe works fine

I did some Googling and found some possible fixes, however they did not work

1. Changing the Dynamic Data Exchange or DDE setting did not help
2. Deleting the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Sheet.12\shell\Open\ddeexec did not help
3. Disabling running Excel as administrator did not help
4. Reassociating the Excel file with Excel did not help

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work if you `start` the .XLSX from a command-prompt?  Does it work as expected while logged into that system as a different user? Does double-clicking an Excel file sitting someplace other than the Desktop work?

Comment: @techie007 I will have to see.  Obviously, if I logged in and it worked, that points to his profile/settings.  What would starting from the cmd prompt tell you if it did or did not work?

Comment: Is this isolated to Excel? Is the PC clean of viruses and malware?

Comment: Only Excel as far as I know.  I cant say with 100% certainty that the computer is clean, but I *believe* it was recently rebuilt and it has AV installed which *should* be up to date.  Honestly, I dont feel its virus/malware related, since other people have reported and resolved this issue do not mention viruses as the problem.

Comment: Since deleting the ddeexec key, have you tried replacing the /dde switch in HKCR\Excel.Sheet.12\shell\open\command with a %1?

Comment: The error could be caused by a 3rd party plugin or add-in. Try to start excel in safe mode (https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Work-with-Office-safe-modes-dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72).

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2010, on the File tab click Options, click Advanced, scroll down to General and untick Ignore other applications...

Similarly for Excel 2007.

In earlier versions you will find this setting under Tools > Options.

For some reason, this setting changes automatically for me every several months and I have to go through this process again.